# How to install collections i a AWX container

Tags: ansible-awx

Is it possible to install collections in a axw container ?

docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                       NAMES
c4d255148cc8   netboxcommunity/netbox:latest   "/opt/netbox/docker-…"   5 days ago   Up 5 days   0.0.0.0:8000->8080/tcp, :::8000->8080/tcp   netbox-docker_netbox_1
ac0784c16861   netboxcommunity/netbox:latest   "/opt/netbox/venv/bi…"   5 days ago   Up 5 days                                               netbox-docker_netbox-worker_1
31b850bf8d12   redis:6-alpine                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago   Up 5 days   6379/tcp                                    netbox-docker_redis-cache_1
df0977f446f4   postgres:12-alpine              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago   Up 5 days   5432/tcp                                    netbox-docker_postgres_1
983b698274af   redis:6-alpine                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago   Up 5 days   6379/tcp                                    netbox-docker_redis_1
4150e6ae71cc   ansible/awx:17.1.0              "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   6 days ago   Up 6 days   8052/tcp                                    awx_task
5583bbf60d45   ansible/awx:17.1.0              "/usr/bin/tini -- /b…"   6 days ago   Up 6 days   0.0.0.0:80->8052/tcp, :::80->8052/tcp       awx_web
c9d92412d1cd   redis                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago   Up 6 days   6379/tcp                                    awx_redis
71b99bde5d41   postgres:12                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago   Up 6 days   5432/tcp                                    awx_postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

- Create a folder: `collections`
- Create file: `requirements.yml`

File content:

```
collections:
- name: community.general
```